# Unexpected token pass style object into a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I use this component rc-tooltip, it has an option to overide the stlye, hence I do

https://www.npmjs.com/package/rc-tooltip

```
<Tooltip 
        trigger={['click']}
        placement={'left'}
        overlayStyle={style={{maxHeight:'250px'}}}
/Tooltip >
```

But it doesn't work, any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a valid syntax in JSX:

```
overlayStyle={style={{maxHeight:'250px'}}}
```

between curly braces you have to pass javascript expressions, in your case you need to pass style object:

```
overlayStyle={{maxHeight:'250px'}}
```

Furthermore, when you pass simple string you don't need it to wrap it with curly braces, it is enaugh to pass string. The complete example would look like:

```
<Tooltip 
  trigger={['click']}
  placement="left"
  overlayStyle={{maxHeight:'250px'}}
/>
```